# jenkins publish over ssh plugin variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to publish a war file over i cannot seem to make a working directory based on date. I also tried this example 'nightly/'yyyy-MM-dd from:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin
but this only outputs an error that directory ' cannot be created.
[image: My configuration]

I also found build_id on some examples, but this also does not work.
How can I create a directory with date as its name prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to create a timestamp variable to use it in the build process itself.
First you have to check to "Change date pattern for BUILD_TIMESTAMP"
and then you define your variable.
[image]

After that you can use it in other plugins like sending it to ssh server:
[image]